# How can I make a button that access a a file in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I've been wanting to make a code that would let me open a directory window and select a csv file from a folder. I wanted to make 4 buttons that would do that, and then one button that if pressed it would run a code and write a new file.

I've tried it several ways but so far i got not much this is my code:

```
from tkinter import*



#how to organize layout#
root = Tk()  #CONSTRUCTOR(think blank window in your head)

topFrame = Frame(root) #this is pretty much saying,
                   # "i'm gonna make an invisible container and is gonna go    into themain window,
                   # root". 

topFrame.pack()        #everytime there is something to display we have to pack it in.

#Do the exact same thing for the bottom frame

bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

#let's through some widgets in here

button1 = Button(topFrame,text="Button1",fg="yellow")
button2 = Button(topFrame,text="Button2",fg="blue")
button3 = Button(topFrame,text="Button3",fg="red")
button4 = Button(topFrame,text="Button4",fg="white")
button5 = Button(bottomFrame,text="Button5",fg="black")

button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3.pack(side=LEFT)
button4.pack(side=LEFT)
button5.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

Comment: `tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory` is probably what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines:

```
from Tkinter import *
def getFile():
    # Get File Code

b = Button(text="click me", command=getFile)
b.pack()
```

By using `command=getFile`, Tk knows to call the `getFile` method when the button is clicked.

Good luck!